# Get full path in Sinatra route including everything after question mark

Tags: ruby, routes, sinatra

I have the following path:

```
http://192.168.56.10:4567/browse/foo/bar?x=100&y=200
```

I want absolutely everything that comes *after* "http://192.168.56.10:4567/browse/" in a string.

Using a splat doesn't work (only catches "foo/bar"):

```
get '/browse/*' do
```

Neither does the regular expression (also only catches "foo/bar"):

```
get %r{/browse/(.*)} do
```

The x and y params are all accessible in the params hash, but doing a .map on the ones I want seems unreasonable and un-ruby-like (also, this is just an example.. my params are actually very dynamic and numerous).  Is there a better way to do this?

More info:  my path looks this way because it is communicating with an API and I use the route to determine the API call I will make.  I need the string to look this way.

Comment: The '/foo/bar' part of the route is always present?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If you are willing to ignore hash tag in path param this should work(BTW browser would ignore anything after hash in URL)

*updated answer*

```
get "/browse/*" do
  p "#{request.path}?#{request.query_string}".split("browse/")[1]
end
```

Or even simpler

```
request.fullpath.split("browse/")[1]
```

Answer (score 1):

```
get "/browse/*" do
  a = "#{params[:splat]}?#{request.env['rack.request.query_string']}"
  "Got #{a}"
end
```